# Asp.net C# Update Panels and DropDown lists data binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

Background that might help you see my problem better:

This is a part of my college Junior Project. My JP is a Volatile Organic Compound sensor, but I wanted to create a website to graphically view the recorded levels as an added bonus. It's not pretty right now, as I am just going for functional first. That being said, what I have done might not be best practice--I am however open to suggestions on how to do this better! I have a 2.5 tier system in place right now--I plan on making 3 tier soon. All 5 dropdown lists have a onselectedindexchange triggers to update the content of the dropdown list below it.

A Zipcode dropdown list ( databound to a query to return a DISTINCT list of zipcodes)

A MonitorID dropdown list ( databound to return all MonitorID's in the Monitor table based upon the zipcode chosen above.)

A Year dropdown list ( databound to return a list of years that the Monitor has been running. For example, "2013, 2014" may be returned and displayed in this dropdown).

A Month Dropdown list (databound to return a list of months that are available based upon selected year)

A Day dropdown list (databound to return a list of days that are available based upon selected month)

My issue is that my month and day dropdown lists are not updating when I select a year and I do not know why. Here is the graph.aspx.cs code

```
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Graph_Outter_Zip" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    Choose a Zip-code:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Graph_DropDownListZip" runat="server" DataSourceID="GetDistinctZip_BL" DataTextField="Zip" DataValueField="Zip" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Graph_DropDownListZip_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetDistinctZip_BL" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetDistinctZip" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    <br />
                    Choose a MonitorID:
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="GetMonitorIDs" DataTextField="MonitorID" DataValueField="MonitorID">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMonitorIDs" runat="server" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetMonitorIDsFromZip" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Graph_DropDownListZip" DefaultValue="97603" Name="zipCode" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

                    <br />
                    Choose a year/month/day to view:
                    <div class="yearDD">
                        Year:<asp:DropDownList ID="GRAPH_yearDropDropList" runat="server" DataSourceID="GetYearFromMonitorID_BL" DataTextField="Year" DataValueField="Year" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GRAPH_yearDropDropList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList> 
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetYearFromMonitorID_BL" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetYearFromMonitorID" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" DefaultValue="1" Name="MonitorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </div>
                    <div class="monthDD">
                        Month:<asp:DropDownList ID="GRAPH_monthDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="GetMonthFromMonitorID" DataTextField="Month" DataValueField="Month" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GRAPH_monthDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetMonthFromMonitorID" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetMonthFromMonitorID" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" DefaultValue="1" Name="MonitorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_yearDropDropList" DefaultValue="2014" Name="Year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayDD">
                        Day:<asp:DropDownList ID="GRAPH_dayDropDownList" runat="server" DataSourceID="GetDayFromMonitorID" DataTextField="Day" DataValueField="Day" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GRAPH_dayDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="GetDayFromMonitorID" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetDayFromMonitorID" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                            <SelectParameters>
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" DefaultValue="1" Name="MonitorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_yearDropDropList" DefaultValue="2014" Name="Year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_monthDropDownList" DefaultValue="04" Name="Month" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                    </div>

                    <asp:Button ID="ViewGraphBtn" runat="server" Text="View Graph" OnClick="ViewGraphBtn_Click" />

                    <asp:Chart ID="Graph" runat="server" DataSourceID="LevelAndTime" OnLoad="Graph_Load" Height="500px" Width="500px">
                        <Series>
                            <asp:Series Name="Level" ChartType="Line" XValueMember="Time" YValueMembers="Level"></asp:Series>
                        </Series>
                        <ChartAreas>
                            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                        </ChartAreas>
                    </asp:Chart>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="LevelAndTime" runat="server" OnSelecting="LevelAndTime_Selecting" SelectMethod="GetLevelAndTimeFromDate" TypeName="Sentient.WebManager.MonitorLevel_BL" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                        <SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" DefaultValue="1" Name="MonitorID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_yearDropDropList" DefaultValue="2014" Name="Year" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_monthDropDownList" DefaultValue="4" Name="Month" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GRAPH_dayDropDownList" DefaultValue="13" Name="Day" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
                        </SelectParameters>
                    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Graph_DropDownListZip" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Graph_DropDownListMonitor" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GRAPH_yearDropDropList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GRAPH_monthDropDownList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="GRAPH_dayDropDownList" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div><!--End Content DIV-->
 </div><!--End ContentWrapper DIV-->
</form>
```

And here is the MonitorLevel_BL.cs Business Layer class code. Not much in the way of business rules so it is pretty straightforward. Yes I hardcoded values into the constructor b/c I was frustrated :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Sentient.WebPersistence.VOCMSDataSetTableAdapters;
using Sentient.WebPersistence;

namespace Sentient.WebManager
{
    public class MonitorLevel_BL
    {
        //Constructor
        public MonitorLevel_BL()
        {
            zipCode = "97601";
            monitorID = 1;
            serialNumber = 0;
            vocID = 0;
            vocName = "";
            protectionInfo = "";
            symptomInfo = "";
            dangerZone = 0;
            year = "2014";
            month = "05";
            day = "15";
        }

    private string _zipCode;
    private int _monitorID;
    private int _serialNumber;
    private int _vocID;
    private string _vocName;
    private string _protectionInfo;
    private string _symptomInfo;
    private int _dangerZone;
    private string _year;
    private string _month;
    private string _day;

    //Setters and Getters
    public string zipCode
    {
        set { _zipCode = value; }
        get { return _zipCode; }
    }

    public int monitorID
    {
        set { _monitorID = value; }
        get { return _monitorID; }
    }

    public int serialNumber
    {
        set { _serialNumber = value; }
        get { return _serialNumber; }
    }

    public int vocID
    {
        set { _vocID = value; }
        get { return _vocID; }
    }

    public string vocName
    {
        set { _vocName = value; }
        get { return _vocName; }
    }

    public string protectionInfo
    {
        set { _protectionInfo = value; }
        get { return _protectionInfo; }
    }

    public string symptomInfo
    {
        set { _symptomInfo = value; }
        get { return _symptomInfo; }
    }

    public int dangerZone
    {
        set { _dangerZone = value; }
        get { return _dangerZone; }
    }

    public string year
    {
        set { _year = value; }
        get { return _year; }
    }

    public string month
    {
        set { _month = value; }
        get { return _month; }
    }

    public string day
    {
        set { _day = value; }
        get { return _day; }
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.DistinctZipcodesDataTable GetDistinctZip()
    {
        DistinctZipcodesTableAdapter distinctZip = new DistinctZipcodesTableAdapter();
        return distinctZip.GetDistinctZipcodes();

    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetYearFromMonitorIDDataTable GetYearFromMonitorID(int MonitorID)
    {
        SP_GetYearFromMonitorIDTableAdapter yearFromMonitorID = new SP_GetYearFromMonitorIDTableAdapter();
        return yearFromMonitorID.GetYearFromMonitorID(MonitorID);
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetMonthFromMonitorIDDataTable GetMonthFromMonitorID(int MonitorID, string Year)
    {

        SP_GetMonthFromMonitorIDTableAdapter month = new SP_GetMonthFromMonitorIDTableAdapter();
        return month.GetMonthFromMonitorID(MonitorID, Year);
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetDayFromMonitorIDDataTable GetDayFromMonitorID(int MonitorID, string Year, string Month)
    {
        SP_GetDayFromMonitorIDTableAdapter day = new SP_GetDayFromMonitorIDTableAdapter();
        return day.GetDayFromMonitorID(MonitorID, Year, Month);
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetMonitorIDsFromZipDataTable GetMonitorIDsFromZip(string zipCode)
    {
        SP_GetMonitorIDsFromZipTableAdapter monitorIDs = new SP_GetMonitorIDsFromZipTableAdapter();
        return monitorIDs.GetMonitorIDsFromZip(zipCode);
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetRawDataToBeDLDataTable GetRawDataToBeDL( int monitorID )
    {
        SP_GetRawDataToBeDLTableAdapter rawData = new SP_GetRawDataToBeDLTableAdapter();
        return rawData.GetRawDataToBeDL(monitorID);
    }

    public VOCMSDataSet.SP_GetLevelAndTimeFromDateDataTable GetLevelAndTimeFromDate(int MonitorID, string Year, string Month, string Day)
    {
        SP_GetLevelAndTimeFromDateTableAdapter levelTime = new SP_GetLevelAndTimeFromDateTableAdapter();
        return levelTime.GetLevelAndTimeFromDate(MonitorID, Year, Month, Day);
    }

}
```

I have unit tested the persistence layer, and the queries are returning the correct information, so I won't bother posting those. Is there some sort of setting that I am missing for the year/month/day dropdown lists?

Comment: Where did you define the event handler "GRAPH_yearDropDropList_SelectedIndexChanged" referenced above?

Comment: My instructors couldn't figure this out.  I am scrapping this in favor of a different way.